# How to wait for multiple observable streams to resolve and return them together

Tags: typescript, firebase, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

In the observable pipeline below `colWithIds$` gives me an observable of a firestore collection (a single array of objects) which I'll refer to as the parent documents. For each of those documents I use `flatMap` to make a single call for an associated document, which I'll call the child documents. I then store the parent and child docs on local variables:

```
this.db.colWithIds$('parentCollection')
  .pipe(
    tap(parentDocs => this.parentDocs = _.keyBy(parentDocs, '_id')),
    flatMap(parentDocs => combineLatest(parentDocs.map(doc => this.db.doc(`childCollection/${doc.childId}`).get()))),
    map(snaps => convertSnaps(snaps)),
    tap(childDocs => this.childDocs = _.keyBy(childDocs, '_id'))
  ).subscribe()
```

The problems with this approach:

1. There is a moment when the parent docs are available, but the child docs are not
2. I would like to put this in a service for reuse, so assigning local variables in this way is problematic.

I'm looking for a way that I can wait until all values have been resolved and return a single object in the following form:

```
{
  parentDocs: [{}, {}, ...], // the documents
  childDocs: [{}, {}, ...], // the documents
}
```

I'm open to other solutions to the problems listed above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? This way you don't query the database twice for parents.

```
this.db.colWithIds$(`parentCollection`).pipe(
  map(parentDocs => _.keyBy(parentDocs, '_id')),
  flatMap(parentDocs => combineLatest(_.map(parentDocs, parent => this.db.docWithId$(`childDocs/${parent.childId}`))).pipe(
    map(childDocs => _.keyBy(childDocs, '_id')),
    map(childDocs => ({parentDocs, childDocs}))
  ))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right what you are trying to do, you could use `forkJoin` which is an operator which receives an array of Observables as input and emits when all Observables in an array have emitted.

In this case your code could look like something similar to the following lines

```
this.db.colWithIds$('parentCollection')
  .pipe(
    // here you use concatMap or switchMap, depending on your logic, to pass
    // the control to the next Observable build using forkJoin
    concatMap(parentDocs => {
       // with this Array map function you create an array of Observables
       const childDocObs = parentDocs.map(doc => this.db.doc(`childCollection/${doc.childId}`).get());
       // here, via forkJoin, you return a single Observable which emits when
       // all the Observables of the childDocObs array have emitted, and what
       // is emitted is an array containing the data emitted by the sing Observables
       // passed in as input
       return forkJoin(childDocObs).pipe(
         // with this map we make sure we return both parentDocs and childDocs
         // without having to use local variables
         map(snaps => {
            const childDocs = convertSnaps(snaps);
            return {parentDocs, childDocs};
         })
       )
    }),
  )
```

This code should therefore returns an Observable which emits `parentDocs` and `childDocs` when all Observables have been resolved.

Comment: I tried forkJoin, but my observable never completes. SwitchMap also only returned a single child, cancelling the others. Additionally I think the observable in an observable pattern is an anti pattern. I posted my solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
getJoinedData(parentId: string): Observable<[ ParentType, ChildType ]> {

  const parent$ = this.db.colWithIds$(`parentCollection`)
    .pipe(map(parentDocs => _.keyBy(parentDocs, '_id')));

  const children$ = parent$.pipe(
    flatMap(parentDocs => combineLatest(_.map(parentDocs, parent => this.db.docWithId$(`childDocs/${parent.childId}`)))),
    map(children => _.keyBy(children, '_id')));

  return combineLatest(parent$, children$);
}
```